# Plotting $\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z| > \Re(z)-2\}$

Tags: complex-numbers

How to plot the set of complex numbers
$$\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z| > \Re(z)-2\}$$

I know that $ |z|$ should be a circle centred at $(0,0)$, but I don't know what would be its radius.

Comment: I think he asks for a plot of the set $\{|z|>R(z)−2\}$.

Comment: The set $\{z\in \mathbf{C}\mid |z| > \Re(z)-2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the plot of a complex number: at best, what you wrote is *the locus of the points of* $\Bbb C$ *which satisfy that inequality*. Specifically, the locus is the whole complex plane, because of the inequalites $$\lvert z\rvert\ge \lvert \Re z\rvert\ge \Re z>-2+\Re z$$ which hold or all $z\in \Bbb C$.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is, with $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ :

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>x-2\implies x^2+y^2>x^2-4x+4\implies y^2>-4(x-1)$$

You have a parabola there...

Comment: @JarekN Do you mean $y^2>4(1-x)?$

Comment: Shouldn't it be 
$y^2>-4(x-1)$

Comment: @JarekN Good catch...and thanks for the editing, Math Lover

Comment: The first "$\implies$" is not true when $x-2<0$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Good point yet let the OP make the usual fixing.

Comment: Such as? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli You really don't get it? Hmmm...well, such as using an absolute value there. Piece of cake.

Comment: Indeed, I did not.